# Still trying to understand mysql to json data

Tags: javascript, php, json

This PHP should return 4 rows of data....
   Row A, Row B, Row C, Row D

```
$query = $mysqli->query("select codeid,description from codeTable where tableCode='TABLE'");
$json = array();
if($query->num_rows){
    while($tblArray[] = $query->fetch_object()){
    $json[]=$tblArray;
    }
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

But in fact, json_encode is showing 10 rows of data....
   Row A, 
   Row A, Row B,
   Row A, Row B, Row C,
   Row A, Row B, Row C, Row D

```
[[{"codeid":"4","description":"Document Type"}],[{"codeid":"4","description":"Document Type"},{"codeid":"8","description":"Images"}],[{"codeid":"4","description":"Document Type"},{"codeid":"8","description":"Images"},{"codeid":"1","description":"Note Type"}],[{"codeid":"4","description":"Document Type"},{"codeid":"8","description":"Images"},{"codeid":"1","description":"Note Type"},{"codeid":"5","description":"Projects"}]]
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?  The end goal is to get the four rows of data returned by the query into a javascript array.

Comment: `while($json[] = $query->fetch_object()) continue; echo json_encode($json);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// remove [] here, or you are adding the row data to an array, then add to another array.
while($tblArray = $query->fetch_object()){
   $json[] = $tblArray;
}
```